# Simulate a ember-select2 selection in ember integration test

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, ember-cli

Has anyone been able to simulate a select2 selection of an option?
So far I've tried this:

```
 test("Checking navigation", function () {
      expect(1);
      visit("/hub");
      click("#btnLogin");
      andThen(function () {
        click(".select2-container");
        andThen(function () {
        });
      });
    });
```

But I have not seen changes in the UI.

Comment: Have you tried to test on what element the event listner is actually set up? Using `$(selector).trigger('click');` in your console? Also: I'd recommend writing a helper function for this sort of stuff so you can easily reuse it in other tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to hit the anchor inside the container

```
  Ember.$(" .select2-container a").trigger({type:'mousedown', which:1});
```

If you want to select an item in the dropdown you can do:

```
Ember.$(".select2-results li div").trigger({type:'mouseup', which:1});
```

Comment: any reason why we use mouseup or mousedown instead of click , and wat does 'which' key denotes

Comment: mouseup is what the select2 listens for, which like cross browser event code @Amerrnath

Comment: Thanks for the answer and response. is there any document for it . Because writing test case for ember-select2. it will be helpful, if you share the resources.

Comment: @Amerrnath this is the doc mate, I had to figure it out by myself.

Comment: with the help of @joostdevries

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
find(".select2-container:first").trigger({type:'mousedown', which:1});
```

Comment: any reason why we use mouseup or mousedown instead of click , and wat does 'which' key denotes

Comment: event.which normalizes button presses (mousedown and mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)