# Simulate a select selection in ember integration test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, qunit

How do you trigger selecting an `<option>` in a `select` element in an integration test? select2 is simple enough: [Simulate a ember-select2 selection in ember integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085394/simulate-a-ember-select2-selection-in-ember-integration-test)

Comment: Do you want to select something or trigger the event?

Comment: @Kitler ets just say I want to select the first option, from the qunit ember-cli test.

Comment: Have you tried [clicking](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Test.html#method_click) on the list and then clicking on the first option?

Comment: just to clarify -is this a integration test or an acceptance test (ie- acceptance has the fillIn helpers/integration does not)

Comment: @ToranBillups acceptnace test

Answer (score 7):

A basic example for ember 1.12 or 1.13+ would use the fillIn helper. I just haven't used it with a jquery select like the one you mention above. Give this a try and report back :)

```
visit("/foobar");
var firstOption = find(".my-select option:eq(0)");
fillIn(".my-select", firstOption.val());
andThen(function() {
  assert.equal(find(".my-select").val(), 78); //assuming 78 is the first options value ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't know the values of the select beforehand?

Comment: So do you have an option you'd like to select? If not ... Maybe explain more about how this should work so I can help :)

Comment: I would just like to trigger the selection of the first option without knowing the value.

Comment: Ah, that should be a simple css selector update (check the code above and let me know if you still don't have a working test).

Comment: @ToranBillups Can it fire "change" event? If no, how can if fire it? If I call ".change()" it fails with "Adapter operation failed".

Comment: Looking at the ember source it should be a simple trigger("input")

Comment: https://gist.github.com/toranb/12364af560832af141ae#file-fillin-helper-js-L12-L13

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this for the underlying event code to be triggered (Ember 2.16):

```
find('select#my-select').val('foo').trigger('change');
```

Comment: nice to see ember is still alive in the wild, still get many clients asking for it?

Comment: @Nikos I'm working on an old project, but I think teams tend to choose react for new projects now. The ember community still looks active though!